# Scala for/yield runs but doesn't complete

Tags: scala

I'm trying to walk through two arrays of potentially different sizes and compose a new array of randomly selected elements from them (for crossover in a genetic algorithm) (childGeneCount is just the length of the longer array).

In the following code snippet, each gene.toString logs, but my code doesn't seem to execute the last log. What dumb thing am I doing?

```
val genes = for (i <- 0 to childGeneCount) yield {
  val gene = if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
    if (i < p1genes.length) {
      p1genes(i)
    } else {
      p2genes(i)
    }
  } else {
    if (i < p2genes.length) {
      p2genes(i)
    } else {
      p1genes(i)
    }
  }
  Logger.debug(gene.toString)
  gene
}
Logger.debug("crossover finishing - never gets here??")
```

New to scala, and would be happy for a slap on the wrist accompanied by a "do it this completely different way instead" if appropriate.

Comment: if `childGeneCount` is length of longer array, you should use `0 until childGeneCount` instead `0 to childGeneCount`. `array(length)` raises an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the problem was with "to" should have been "until". I have changed your code a bit to make it more scala like.

```
  val p1genes = "AGTCTC"
  val p2genes = "ATG"

  val genePair = p1genes.zipAll(p2genes, None, None)
  val matchedGene = for (pair <- genePair) yield {
    pair match {
      case (p1Gene, None) => p1Gene
      case (None, p2Gene) => p2Gene
      case (p1Gene, p2Gene) => if (Random.nextBoolean()) p1Gene else p2Gene
    }
  }
  println(matchedGene)
```

The process is:

1. First zip two dna sequences into one.
2. Fill the shorter sequence with None.
3. Now loop over the zipped sequences and populate the new sequence.

Comment: By combining letters with `None`s in one sequence the result is of a type `IndexedSeq[Any]`.

Comment: This is nice, I didn't know about `zipAll`!
One thing it doesn't take into account is that you can know exactly when `None` will appear (the whole end of the originally smaller sequence). Another problem is that you're mixing `Char`s with `Option` so you need to use `genes.map(Some.apply)` on `p1genes` and `p2genes` to preserve your types.

Comment: Once could use some specific character (like '-') known not to appear in the DNA instead of the `None` marker, or transform the whole sequence to Some first (in full shown in my answer).

Comment: Thanks, did not know about `.map(Some.apply)` .

Answer (score 2):

Reworked Tawkir's answer, with cleaner `None` handling:

```
val p1genes = "AGTCTC"
val p2genes = "ATG"

val genePair = p1genes.map(Some.apply).zipAll(p2genes.map(Some.apply), None, None)
val matchedGene = genePair.map {
  case (Some(p1Gene), None) => p1Gene
  case (None, Some(p2Gene)) => p2Gene
  case (Some(p1Gene), Some(p2Gene)) => if (Random.nextBoolean()) p1Gene else p2Gene
}
println(matchedGene)
```

If you want to avoid wrapping the sequence with `Some`, another solution is to use a character known not to appear in the sequence as a "none" marker:

```
val p1genes = "AGTCTC"
val p2genes = "ATG"

val none = '-'
val genePair = p1genes.zipAll(p2genes, none, none)
val matchedGene = genePair.map {
  case (p1Gene, `none`) => p1Gene
  case (`none`, p2Gene) => p2Gene
  case (p1Gene, p2Gene) => if (Random.nextBoolean()) p1Gene else p2Gene
}
println(matchedGene)
```

Comment: great, thanks for the rework. I guess the marker solution looks better. The Some.apply feels like to much engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure harry0000's answer is correct: I was using "to" like "until", and am so used to exceptions being thrown loudly that I didn't think to look there!

I ended up switching from for/yield to `List.tabulate(childGeneCount){ i => {`, which fixed the error probably for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for possible style improvements, here are two suggested implementations. The first one is less idiomatic, but more performant. The second one is prettier but does some more work.

```
  def crossover[E : ClassTag](a: Array[E], b: Array[E]): Array[E] = {
    val (larger, smaller) = if(a.length > b.length) (a, b) else (b, a)
    val result = Array.ofDim[E](larger.length)
    for(i <- smaller.indices)
      result(i) = if(Random.nextBoolean()) larger(i) else smaller(i)
    for(i <- smaller.length until larger.length)
      result(i) = larger(i)
    result
  }


  def crossoverIdiomatic[E : ClassTag](a: Array[E], b: Array[E]): Array[E] = {
    val randomPart = (a zip b).map { case (x,y) => if(Random.nextBoolean()) x else y }
    val (larger, smaller) = if(a.length > b.length) (a, b) else (b, a)
    randomPart ++ larger.drop(smaller.length)
  }

  val a = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
  val b = Array("one", "two", "three", "four")

  // e.g. output: [one,2,three,4,5,6]
  println(crossover(a, b).mkString("[", ",", "]"))
  println(crossoverIdiomatic(a, b).mkString("[", ",", "]"))
```

Note that the `E : ClassTag` are only there to make the compiler happy about using `Array[E]`, if you only need `Int` for your work, you can drop all the fancy generics.